# Python calculate pairwise distance with own distance function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a distance function which takes two integers

```
def GeneDistance(gene1,gene2):
```

I want to use this function to calculate a distance matrix of this PandasSeries:

```
Gene Name
yjiQ      4569358
yjiP      4568998
yjhE      4506861
phnE_2    4322811
yifN      3960460
yrhA      3583041
```

Distance Matrix:

```
Gene    yjiQ    yjiP    yjhE    phnE_2  yifN
yjiQ    0       value   value   value   value
yjiP    value   0       value   value   value
yjhE    value   value   0       value   value
phnE_2  value   value   value   0   
yifN    value   value   value   value   0
yrhA    value   value   value   value   value
yghE    value   value   value   value   value
ygeN    value   value   value   value   value
```

I tried to use sklearn.metrics.pairwise

```
pairwise_distances(array, metric=GeneDistance)
```

with that array:

```
array([['yjiQ', 4569358],
       ['yjiP', 4568998],
       ['yjhE', 4506861],
       ..., 
       ['araB', 70048],
       ['araA', 68337],
       ['garL', 3273557]], dtype=object)
```

But it tries to use the string as a value

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: garL
```

**UPDATE:**
It seems like it worked with this reshape function because I only have one feature:

```
DistanceMatrix = pairwise_distances(DistanceAnnotation["Gene Start"].reshape(-1,1), metric=GeneDistance)

DistanceMatrix = pd.DataFrame(DistanceMatrix)
DistanceMatrix["Gene Name"] = DistanceAnnotation["Gene Name"]
DistanceMatrix.set_index("Gene Name", inplace=True)
DistanceMatrix.columns = list(DistanceAnnotation["Gene Name"])
```

Comment: The array it expects is not supposed to contain headers. As a result i supposed it respects the original order so you can add those afterwards. Also please paste the definition of your distance-measuring function. Is it configured to handle headers?

Comment: maybe pairwise_distances() only needs the numeric component of your PandasSeries? try using the help(sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances) to read documentation for that function to understand what the arguments should be.